# Connecting to db2 from java client

Tags: maven, jdbc, db2, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to connect to db2 from a java client running the application as a jar. The jar is a super-jar with all dependencies generated by the shade plugin.

When I run the program from my ide(Netbeans) it runs fine, but when I run it from commandline like this it fails:
`java -jar target/locationImporter.jar`

The exception I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.as400.access.PortMapper.getServerSocket(PortMapper.java:216)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.signonConnect(AS400ImplRemote.java:2363)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.signon(AS400ImplRemote.java:2278)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.sendSignonRequest(AS400.java:3142)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.promptSignon(AS400.java:2706)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.signon(AS400.java:4035)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.connectService(AS400.java:1184)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnection.setProperties(AS400JDBCConnection.java:3338)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.prepareConnection(AS400JDBCDriver.java:1419)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.initializeConnection(AS400JDBCDriver.java:1256)
    at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver.connect(AS400JDBCDriver.java:395)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at dataprep.ConnectionSupplier.getConnection(ConnectionSupplier.java:18)
    at dataprep.SqlFileRunner.runScript(SqlFileRunner.java:65)
    at dataprep.SqlFileRunner.runSqlFile(SqlFileRunner.java:26)
    at dataprep.PrepareDatabase.main(PrepareDatabase.java:26)
```

The code that fails is:

```
Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver").newInstance();
return DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, JDBC_USER, JDBC_PASSWORD);
```

Since it runs in my ide, I know that the url, user and password is correct.

My shade plugin is configured like this in my pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
        <shadedClassifierName>launcher</shadedClassifierName> 
        <finalName>locationImporter</finalName>
        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: it appears that the shade plugin does not include the socketcontainerInet file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging a colleague of mine pointed me in the right direction. Removing the `minimizeJar` fixes the problem  since the shade plugin removed the file "SocketContainerInet" since it was not directly instantiated but via a string-value..